# An inequality associated with sum of n real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers, karamata-inequality

Let $x_i\geq 1, 1\leq i\le n.$   Then show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_i}\leq \frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{1+x_1x_2\cdots x_n}.$$
One method of proving this is induction on $n.$ This can be achieved by the fact; for $n=2,$  $ \frac{1}{1+x_1}+\frac{1}{1+x_2}\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1+x_1x_2}.$ This idea can be extended to complete the proof of induction.

I am curious to know if you have any  alternative attractive proofs! Solutions using multivariable  calculus techniques are  also welcome.

Possibility of sharpening; I was wondering if the bound can be sharpened further, especially with  terms containing symmetric functions of $x_1,.....x_n?$

Comment: What is the point in defining the $y_i$ ? This is equivalent to show directly that $\sum \frac{1}{1+x_i} \leq \frac{n-1}{2} + \frac{1}{1+x_1x_2...x_n}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your new inequality we can prove by Karamata for the concave on $[0,+\infty)$  function $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}$.

Indeed, for $x\geq0$ we obtain:
$$f''(x)=\frac{2e^x(1-e^x)}{(e^x+1)^3}\leq0.$$
Now, let $x_i=e^{a_i}.$

Thus, $a_i\geq0$ and we need to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{1+x_i}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{1+x_1...x_n}-\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-1}{x_i+1}\geq\frac{x_1...x_n-1}{x_1...x_n+1}.$$
Now, let $x_1\geq x_2\geq...\geq x_n.$

Thus, $$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n,0,...,0)\succ(a_1,a_2,...a_n),$$ which by Karamata gives:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-1}{x_i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{e^{a_i}-1}{e^{a_i}+1}\geq\frac{e^{a_1+...+a_n}-1}{e^{a_1+...+a_n}+1}=\frac{x_1...x_n-1}{x_1...x_n+1}$$ and we are done!

Comment: Great. Thank you very much

Comment: @user159888 You are welcome!

Comment: @user159888 You did not accept my answer, which says for me that you don't want to use a multivariable-calculus here. Am I right?

Comment: @user159888 Please, you don't need to accept my answer. I just want to get an answer on the question in my previous comment. Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate the approach.

Comment: @user159888 If so, say please in your starting post that solutions by multivariables calculus are also valid. Thank you!