# Proving an inequality with n positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Is there any alternative  way of proving
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k-1}{a_k+1}\geq\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n a_k -1}{\prod_{k=1}^na_k+1}$$ for any positive real numbers $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n,$  greater than or equal to 1, other than the one   given in one of the the answers; [An inequality associated with sum of n real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801573/an-inequality-associated-with-sum-of-n-real-numbers)?

Comment: If you *read* the proof you've quoted, you'll notice that it works only for $a_k\ge1$, not for any positive real numbers. Indeed, the statement is false for $n=2, a_1=a_2=1/2$.

Comment: Sorry I missed out to add  that condition. Thanks for bringing it into my notice. Now I rectified.

Answer (score 1):

We write the inequality as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i+1}\leq \frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2\cdots a_n+1}. \quad (1)$$
For $n=1$ the inequality become
$$\frac{1}{a_1+1}+\frac{1}{a_2+1} \leqslant \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{a_1a_2+1}, \quad (2)$$
or
$$\frac{(a_1-1)(a_2-1)(a_1a_2-1)}{2(a_1+1)(a_2+1)(a_1a_2+1)} \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true.

Now, let $x=a_1a_2 \cdots a_k,$ suppose $(1)$ is true for $n=k,$ we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{a_i+1} \leqslant \frac{k-1}{2}+\frac{1}{x+1}. \quad (3)$$
We will show that this is also true for $n=k+1.$

Indeed, setting $y = a_{k+1},$ use $(3)$ and $(2)$ we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{a_i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{a_i+1} + \frac{1}{y+1} \leqslant \frac{k-1}{2}+\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{y+1}$$
$$\leqslant \frac{k-1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{xy+1} = \frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{x_1x_2\cdots x_{k+1}+1}.$$
Done.